# How do I recover my account after switching from Android to iOS?

Tags: dragonvale

I recently switched from an Android to an iOS phone but I can't recover my Dragonvale account, although in the Android device I did save it on my Facebook account.
I tried logging in with the Facebook account but it makes me start over.

It's frustrating because I had a lot of rare dragons...

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you will have to start over. [From the FAQ](http://www.backflipstudios.com/help/androidfaq/):

> **Can I play my iOS (Apple) DragonVale park on my Android device or vice versa?**
>
> DragonVale accounts and their data are NOT transferable between iOS (Apple) and Android devices.  You cannot access your iOS (Apple) DragonVale park from an Android device nor can you access your Android DragonVale park from an iOS (Apple) device.

Answer (score 0):

You should get a message that said:

> Two different park levels were found on your account. Which park would you like to sync to?" Choices are "LV 1" and "LV 35.

So if you clicked "cancel" or "Level 1" Therre is nothing you can do.

Answer (score 0):

Try signing back in to game center or Facebook, or whichever you use. This happened to me once, and I was really upset 'cause I had tons of rare and epic dragons, then it turned out I had been logged out of game center. So just see if you're logged out!

Answer (score -1):

You should just try facebook again. Sorry but there is no other way i can think of. Also, I think there is a separate account for your facebook and local account.